# Can one make meaningful predictions from "censored data"?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, censoring

In an ML project, I'm using patients' clinical and demographic features to predict their treatment outcomes. Among over 300K records, only 6,022 are known to have experienced severe conditions (ICU, unstable, death, etc.) and for the rest, severity is unclear (e.g., hospitalized, under treatment).

Here it seems only "severe" is meaningful whereas "not severe" could suggest anything (e.g., actually not severe or we just don't know). However, this imperfect dataset might be the most comprehensive one on this particular disease.

My question is, can you make a meaningful predictive model out of censored data? If that's something people do, would you point me to resources on how to do so? Thank you so much!

Comment: I believe you are looking for an approach called survival analysis.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov Survival analysis can indeed deal with censored data but what it predicts is time until the next event, which doesn’t seem relevant?

Comment: It can predict any number of things, depending on the model. Perhaps it might help if you clarify what you data structure and variables looks like and the sorts of things you want to predict with this model.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov I think I mentioned in the question that I'm predicting treatment outcomes (severe vs. not severe) based on patient features. Features can be binary (has X, Y, Z clinical condition or not) or continuous (e.g., age). Can survival analysis predict the probability of an outcome (rather than time until that outcome happens again)?

Comment: It can predict the hazard rate of transition to severe, which is related to the probability. But using this approach would require transforming your "snapshot" data to time-span data, which may not be possible. Another idea I had is that perhaps you can re-define your outcome to be severe within some fixed time window of the treatment. In the end, however, if this is just a predictive exercise, you can test the performance on some data held out from the model to get a sense of how good your model is.